# How to clear descendent elements of specific element in Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have HTML template similar to below

```
<div id="mainId">
    <div>
        <custom-element>
            <div>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                .......
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </custom-element>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to clear all the `<p>` elements inside the `mainId`, I tried getting all the paragraph tags using `querySelectorAll` in JavaScript as shown below

```
document.querySelectorAll('#mainId > div > custom-element > div > p')
```

but, is there any other way in Angular to get all the descendent nodes by using above id `mainId` and **clear** all paragraphs under it?

Comment: Don't manipulate the DOM "manually" using query selectors and who knows what DOM API remove method. If your paragraphs are generated using a ngFor directive (since you say that you have possible multiple paragraphs), you could use a ngIf directive on the same paragraph where you have the ngFor and that condition would "take care" of removing the paragraphs based on the passed in condition. It would help if you would describe why / when / how those paragraphs would have to be removed.

Comment: `<div *ngIf="variable"><p></p><p></p></div>`. Just only declare a variable and give value true or false

Comment: @CCBet  You are right we should not manually manipulate DOM so only I'm in need of some better solution. Actually paragraph is just an example, it may not be <p> tag it can be any element, I need some better solution of for reaching to some specific element/descendent from parent element

Comment: @VIK6Galado, you could look into https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables , https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild and https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren